# How to get all objects using Berkeley DB meeting a condition

Tags: java, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I just found out about Berkeley DB and its performance yesterday. I'm willing to use it in a Java project.

What I would like to know is, how to get all objects stored in my DB that meet a certain condition.

For example, I have objects of type **Message(int id, String value, Date date)** stored, and I would like to get all the messages of the last 10 minutes.

In other words, what is the equivalent of this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE date < 2016-04-12T23:20:50.52Z
```

in Berkeley DB.

Is it possible to do it with Berkeley DB's API or I should do it all by coding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Berkeley DB is a key-value store.  If you want to do anything more sophisticated than get/set values by their identifiers, you're going to have to do the work.  There is an SQL module for it.  I've never used it, but I wouldn't place too many chips on that number.

A problem such as you pose is *much* better solved in SQLite, which uses something like Berkeley DB under the hood, and (of course) supports SQL.  It also supports date arithmetic on correctly formatted strings.